# Pthread program printing different values on Codeblocks and Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, codeblocks

I'm working on the following pthread program that finds the number of substrings in string2 that are in string1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 4
#define MAX 1024

int n1,n2,i;
char *s1,*s2;
FILE *fp;

char *substring(char *string, int position, int length);
void *occurrence();


int readf(FILE *fp)
{
    if((fp=fopen("strings.txt", "r"))==NULL){
        printf("ERROR: can't open strings.txt!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    s1=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX);
    if(s1==NULL){
        printf("ERROR: Out of memory!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    s2=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX);
    if(s1==NULL){
        printf("ERROR: Out of memory\n");
        return -1;
    }
    /*read s1 s2 from the file*/
    s1=fgets(s1, MAX, fp);
    s2=fgets(s2, MAX, fp);
    n1=strlen(s1);  /*length of s1*/
    n2=strlen(s2)-1; /*length of s2*/
    if(s1==NULL || s2==NULL || n1<n2)  /*when error exit*/
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, occurrence, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    exit(0);
}

char *substring(char *string, int position, int length)
{
    char *pointer;
    int c;

    pointer = malloc(length+1);

    if (pointer == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (c = 0 ; c < length ; c++)
    {
        *(pointer+c) = *(string+position-1);
        string++;
    }

    *(pointer+c) = '\0';

    return pointer;
}

void* occurrence()
{
    char *string1;
    char *string2;
    char *new_str;
    int counter=0;
    readf(fp);

    string1 = s1;
    string2 = s2;
    new_str = malloc(200);
    for(i=1;i<=strlen(string1);i++)
    {
        new_str = substring(string1,i,strlen(string2));
        if(strcmp(new_str, string2)==0)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    printf("The number of substrings is: %d \n",counter);
    return 0;
}
```

When i compile it on codeblocks, it prints the correct number of substrings. However, when I compile it on the Linux kernel, it always prints 1 as the number of substrings, even though there's more than one. For example, a `strings.txt` file that has **abdeabjhab** in the first line and **ab** in the 2nd line should print 3, since there's 3 instances of *ab* in the first line. My Linux kernel prints 1. **Is there a specific way I'm supposed to compile it for it to print the right value?** I'm current using `gcc -pthread substring.c -o substrings` to compile and `./substrings` to execute it.

Comment: `when I compile it on the Linux kernel` - You compile this program for Linux, not for Linux **kernel**, which has different API. Also, opposition of "CodeBlocks" and "Linux" is wrong: The first is a **build system**, but the second is **Operating System**.

Comment: You do not appear to actually _use_ multithreading; you just create a single thread that runs the entire computation and immediately wait for it.  That means you perfectly well could call `occurrence` directly.  If you make that change, does that make the problem go away?  The other thing I would like you to try is eliminating all of the global variables.

Comment: I haven't verified but I suspect `for(i=1;i<=strlen(string1);i++)` may be the source of some problems. Memory offsets in `c` start at 0. That's true for pointers and arrays. Since you're starting at 1 instead of 0 there could be some off-by-1 errors somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here.

First the signature for `occurrence` is wrong; the thread function should take a `void*` as argument and return a `void*` as required by the [pthread_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) API. So it should be:

```
void *occurrence(void*);
```

and

```
void *occurrence(void arg*) {
    ...
    return NULL;
}
```

There are several other questionable things in your code.

- You are passing the global variable `fp` to `readf()` function. Why do you need to pass a global variable?
- You are reading only the first two lines. What if the file contains many more lines?
- Why do you have `s1` and `s2` as global? You could easily rewrite it to pass from `readf` back to `occurrence`. Or `occurrence` could pass varibles that `readf` writes into.
- You don't close the file with `fclose`.
- You create just one thread to do the work and the main thread just waits for it. So there's no real need for threads here. You might as well let the main thread do the work and not bother with threads.
- Why do you subtract here?: `n2=strlen(s2)-1; /*length of s2*/`.
  What if the length of `s1` and `s2` are the same? Is `"abc"` not a substring of `"abc"`?

Your actual of problem of getting incorrect substring count is probably because [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html) reads in the newline character and thus the substring match fails.

To remove newlines, you can do in your `readf` function after reading `s1` and `s2`:

```
char *p = strchr(s1, '\n');
if (p) *p = 0;
p = strchr(s2, '\n');
if (p) *p = 0;
```

This should fix the immediate problem. But there's a lot you could improve.